Weak star convergence + $L^2$ strong convergence implies $L^p$ strong convergence
I want to understand why the following should hold.
Suppose $U$ is a bounded domain. If $\{f_n\}_n$ converges weak-* in $L^\infty(U)$ to some $f$ and also the convergence holds strongly in $L^2(U)$. Can you conclude that there is a strong convergence also in $L^p(U)$ for $2 < p < \infty$?
Now I know that the weak-* convergence in $L^\infty(U)$ implies a weak convergence of a subsequence in $L^p(U)$. Can we conclude that it is a strong convergence (of subsequence) in $L^p(U)$ given the $L^2$ strong convergence?

By the uniform bounded principle there is $c>$ such
that $\|f_n\|_\infty\le c.$ Let $\|f_n-f\|_2\to 0.$
Then $f$ is bounded and $\|f\|_\infty \le c.$
Let $g_n=f_n-f.$ Then $\|g_n\|_2\to 0$ and $\|g_n\|_\infty\le 2c.$ For $p>2$ we get
$$\int |g_n(x)|^p\,dx=\int |g_n(x)|^
{p-2}|g_n(x)|^2\,dx\\ \le \|g_n\|_\infty^{p-2}\|g_n\|_2^2\le (2c)^{p-2}\|g_n\|_2^2 $$ Thus $\|g_n\|_p\to 0.$ This reasoning does not make use of the boundedness of the domain.
